# PhpStorm / Google AppEngine with PHP7

Tags: google-app-engine, phpstorm, php-7, google-cloud-sdk

I recently deployed my app using Google App Engine. I installed Google Cloud SDK and I'm using PhpStorm.

When I run my app using `runtime : php55`, it works. But I need PHP 7!

When I try with

```
runtime: php

env: flex

A error occured : flex, only the following runtimes are allowed: ('python-compat', 'java', 'java7', 'go', 'custom')
```

Do you have an idea?

Here is my app.yaml config:

[image]

Here is my composer.json config:

[image]

Here is my PhpStorm config:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error you shared appears when deploying the application to the App Engine Flexible environment, or when testing locally with the Development Server?

Comment: Testing locally with the Development Server !

Comment: Ok, have a look at my answer. Next time I recommend you to share your code as a snippet or code sample, rather than a screenshot, so that it is easier for other users to answer back with some modifications, if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the comments to the question, I see you are working with the Development Server, which [does not support the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/using-local-server#running_the_local_development_server). The Development Server only supports the runtime environments available for App Engine Standard, which are **Java 7** (now deprecated) and **8**, **Go 1.6**, **Python 2.7** and **PHP 5.5**.

However, it also supports [*custom environments*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build), which allows you to work in any programming language just by supplying a base Dockerfile image that configures the runtime environment (in your case you can build yourself an appropriate image with a PHP 7 environment or download it from an existent repository). It requires of course some more complex configuration and management than that of the provided Development Server, but right now, that is the only way you will be able to work with PHP in the development for App Engine.

So the configuration of your application should be correct, it is just that the Development Server does not yet support the Flexible Environment that you need to develop in PHP 7.